# Visual Studio: assign a key to maximize edit window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

How can I assign a hotkey to maximize the edit window?

Basically I want the equivalent of:

- switch to edit window + minimize all side panes
- or at least just minimize all side panes (and leaving the menu and toolbar as is)

---

NOTE: this is different than full screen, I do not want to change the size of the VS window itself.

I need this on Visual Studio 2017 / 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Short of some sort of macro I thing the best way is probably like this:-

1. Setup the windows in VS as you want them to look
2. Save that as a layout.
3. Assign a hotkey to the Switch to layout command.

Comment: but can I then switch back ?

Comment: Save your original layout and assign a different hotkey to switch to that

Answer (score 1):

[Hot Windows](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotWindows) extension provides shortcuts to hide and show all tool windows (e.g. Shift+Alt+Ins).